# List all directories that contain a file with a particular extension

Tags: linux, grep

I need list all the directories that contain a file with .info extension in the first level.

```
  --contrib
     --abc
       --ab.info 
     --def
       --de.info 
     --xyz
       --ab.gh
       --ab.ij
```

The command should list

```
abc, def
```

Comment: find . -iname "*.info"?

Comment: I just need the folder names. Not the full path of the file.

Comment: Try `find . -name "*info" -type f;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work if you run it from your contrib directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*.info" -exec dirname {} \;
```

It will need more tweaking if you actually want to run it from the parent of contrib.

The above will give you:

```
./abc
./def
```

Which is not exactly what you wanted. So maybe something more like this will help:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*.info" -exec sh -c 'F=$(dirname {}) ; basename $F' \;
```

It is more convoluted but the result is:

```
abc
def
```

Or without `basename` and `dirname`:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*.info" -exec bash -c '[[ {} =~ .*/(.*)/.* ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}' \;
```

Or with `sed`:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name "*.info" -exec echo {} + | sed 's|./\(\S*\)/\S*|\1,|g'
```

Result:

```
abc, def,
```